# Как определить путь к текстуре модели в Arcgis?

Tags: c++, qt, текстура, arcgis

Можно менять текстуру у добавленной модели в Arcgis ?
У меня добавляется модель на сцену так :

```
void ViewshedGeoElement::createGraphic()
{
    // Create the Graphic Point
    const double x = -4.508708007847015;
    const double y = 48.38823243446344;
    const double z = 0;
    const Point tankPoint(x, y, z, SpatialReference(4326));
    const QString dataPath = QQmlProperty::read(this, "dataPath").toString();
    const float scale = 1;

    // Create the Graphic Symbol
    ModelSceneSymbol* sceneSymbol = new ModelSceneSymbol(QUrl(dataPath + "/2C19Msta-C/2c19Msta.3DS"), scale, this);
    sceneSymbol->setAnchorPosition(SceneSymbolAnchorPosition::Bottom);
    sceneSymbol->setHeading(180.0f);

    // Create the Graphic
    QVariantMap attr;
    attr[m_headingAttr] = 150.0;
    m_tank = new Graphic(tankPoint, attr, sceneSymbol, this);

//    m_tank->setVisible(false);
    m_graphicsOverlay->graphics()->append(m_tank);
}
```

Как ей можно задать другую текстуру ? Я хочу менять текстуру у модели в своей программе. В документации не нашёл как задавать разные текстуры у модели .

2c19Msta1.obj

```
    # 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
    # File Created: 02.04.2019 12:21:56

    mtllib 2c19Msta1.mtl

    #
    # object Msta
    #

    v  0.1041 2.1888 0.8995
    v  0.1177 2.1896 0.8766
    v  0.0851 2.2456 0.8697
...
```

2c19Msta1.mtl

```
# 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 02.04.2019 12:21:56

newmtl green
    Ns 10.0000
    Ni 1.5000
    d 1.0000
    Tr 0.0000
    Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
    illum 2
    Ka 0.5880 0.5880 0.5880
    Kd 0.5880 0.5880 0.5880
    Ks 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
    map_Ka C:\Users\52\ArcGIS\Runtime\Data\3D\2c19Msta\msta.png
    map_Kd C:\Users\52\ArcGIS\Runtime\Data\3D\2c19Msta\msta.png
```

Comment: `2c19Msta.3DS` знакомая гаубица недавно делал часть VR тренажера для нее,  забавно =) вобщем-то текстура вписана в сам 3ds файл..

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Я это понимаю что текстура вписана сама в 3ds файл, в коде можно менять путь до текстуры?

Comment: проще нужную текстуру сунуть по известному пути

Comment: 3ds достаточно хитрый формат, там может быть много текстур и где какая описано внутри файла, как вы будете привязки осуществлять где диффузная текстура а где карта нормалей или где еще там что-то что поддерживает формат?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А если .obj формат использовать ? Он открытый , только в Arcgis у меня добавляется модель без текстур

Comment: с `obj` в паре должен идти `mtl`(описание материала), я бы использовал формат `collada`? если arcgis его поддерживает

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Он не открытый и если obj 1.5 Mb то collada 15 Mb будет весить

Comment: @Stranger in the Q в obj у меня файл .mtl  рядом лежит.....но он не подхватывается arcgis. Хотя я пути точные прописал

Comment: коллада как раз открытый формат, по крайней мере тут так написано https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA

Comment: а с чего Вы решили что коллада в 10 раз больше? если вы взглянете внутрь там весь размер это векторы, она может быть пухлой из за анимации это да, но если obj конвертнуть 1в1 в колладу оно не сильно вырастет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91852/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Хорошо. Спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: а приложете ка mtl файл, он же не большой

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  Есть идеи что не так с путями ?

Comment: да есть одна идея, пробовали убирать абсолютный путь? mtl вообще читается? если там руками зеленый цвет материала где-нибудь задать например.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q пробовал разные пути задавать и даже использовал / и \ ....кавычки пробовал "" такие и такие ' '

Comment: вот так: "./texture.png" ?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q нет не хочет цеплять сейчас ещё в другой проект попробую

Comment: добавить .....посмотрим будет работать